# Question where the exponent is the square root of a log

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

$4^{\sqrt{\log_4(5)}}  -5^{\sqrt{\log_5(4)}}$

The answer is 0 but I do not understand why.  I assume you can group the two terms somehow.  The question would be much easier if it weren't for the square roots

Comment: You can use $\log_4(5) = \frac{\log(5)}{\log(4)}$ and $\log_5(4)=\frac{\log(4)}{\log(5)}$. This helps to make everything consistent.  Here $\log()$ denotes the natural log.  [PS: I didn't downvote this question]  You can also use $4^x = \exp(x \log(4))$.

Answer (score 4):

Follow the steps below,

$$4^{\sqrt{\log_4 5}}  =5^{\sqrt{\log_4 5 }}$$

Take $\ln()$ on both sides,

$$ \sqrt{\log_4 5}\ln 4 = \sqrt{\log_5 4} \ln 5$$

Square both sides and use $\log_a b=\ln b/\ln a$,

$$  (\ln 5/ \ln 4)\ln^2 4 = (\ln4/ \ln 5) \ln^2 5$$

$$  \ln 5 \ln 4= \ln4 \ln 5 $$

Answer (score 2):

$4^{\sqrt{\log_4 5}} = k > 4$ (because $\log_4 5 > 1$)

So $5 = 4^{\log_4 5} = (4^{\sqrt{\log_4 5}})^{\sqrt{\log_4  5}} = k^{\sqrt{\log_4 5}}$

Meanwhile $(5^{\sqrt{\log_5 4}})^{\sqrt{\log_4  5}}=5^{\sqrt{\log_54 \cdot \log_4 5}} = 5^1 = 5= k^{\sqrt{\log_4 5}}$.

So $ (4^{\sqrt{\log_4 5}})^{\sqrt{\log_4  5}}=(5^{\sqrt{\log_5 4}})^{\sqrt{\log_4  5}}$

$x^b$ is an invertible function for $x\in \mathbb R$ and $b>0; b\ne 1$.

So $4^{\sqrt{\log_4 5}} = 5^{\sqrt{\log_5 4}}$

Answer (score 1):

Because $$4^{\sqrt{\log_45}}=e^{\ln4\sqrt{\frac{\ln5}{\ln4}}}=e^{\ln5\sqrt{\frac{\ln4}{\ln5}}}=5^{\sqrt{\log_54}}.$$